# ScrollViewer enveloping a Grid not working properly

Tags: wpf, grid, scrollviewer

I am facing a strange problem with the ScrollViewer

I have a ScrollViewer with a Grid inside. The height of the Grid requires a vertical scrollbar. At runtime, the scrollbar is visible, but appears disabled and has no scroll indicator between the two arrows.

However, just above this scrollviewer is another set of controls enveloped by a scroll viewer, actually just the wayas the above, but here the scroll viewer is working just fine

here's the code

```
<Grid><Canvas Height="250" Width ="400" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="White" Name="ModeCanvas">
                    <Rectangle Width="{Binding ElementName=ModeCanvas,Path=ActualWidth}" Height="{Binding ElementName=ModeCanvas,Path=ActualHeight}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                    <Grid Height="244" Width ="394" Margin="3,3,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="ModeParent">
                            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
                                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="ModeGrid" >
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Canvas>
                <Canvas Height="250" Width="400" Margin="0,255,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="White" Name="InputDataCanvas">
                    <Rectangle Width="{Binding ElementName=InputDataCanvas,Path=ActualWidth}" Height="{Binding ElementName=InputDataCanvas,Path=ActualHeight}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                    <Grid Margin="5,5,5,5" Width="390" Height="240" Name="InputDataParent">
                        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
                            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="InputDataGrid" >
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </Canvas>
                <Canvas Margin="0,510,0,0" Height="250" Width ="400" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="White" Name="OutputDataCanvas">
                    <Rectangle Width="{Binding ElementName=OutputDataCanvas,Path=ActualWidth}" Height="{Binding ElementName=OutputDataCanvas,Path=ActualHeight}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" />
                    <Grid Margin="5,5,5,5" Width="390" Height="240" Name="OutputDataParent">                        
                            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="OutputDataGrid">
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </Canvas>
```

In this code -  the first 2 Canvas render the scrollbar just fine, but for some reason the third one is creating a problem

Any Ideas ??

**EDIT**

Finally got the mistake in the code. The probelm was in the code behind.

The basic probelm was that when we resize the window at that time some code behind code was changing the heights of the first 2 Grids but not of the third Grid. Initially the data that was inserted in each Grid(dynamically) was such that, the first 2 Grids used to overflow but not the 3rd one, . So, now when i resized the window the third Grid still did not have a scroll viewer even though now the data was overflowing the space,giving an impression that the scroll viewer was not activating.

However, i missed the simple fact, that the height of the 3rd grid was not changing, whereas the first 2 Grids height was changing, thus the scroll viewer for the first 2 grids was properly working but not the 3rd.

Comment: Ive run your code and all 3 scroll viewers work fine - there must be some additional into - can you give me more xaml

Comment: the Data within the scroll viewers Grid gets added dynamically, so what you must have seen is just the empty ScrollViewers.. once data gets poulted within these scroll Viewers, you would observe that for the first 2 canvas scrollviewers get activated properly but not for the 3rd one..

Answer (score 0):

The Grid inside the ScrollViewer is empty. What the scrollviewer is expect to scroll?

Comment: the Grid gets dynamically filled up by controls.

Comment: The controls added in the 3rd scrollviewer are visible? Their max occupation is larger than the scrollviewer area? However, I guess you messed up the xaml. Why so many nested grids? You may define a grid layout.